# How can I bake many Rigid Body objects to keyframes at once?

Tags: keyframes, baking, rigid-body-simulation

I have an absolute ton of different objects in a Rigid Body simulation and I’m wondering: Is there a way to bake them all to keyframes at once? I just simply can’t do them individually.

Comment: Doesn't selecting all objects and doing *Object > Rigid Body > Bake To Keyframes* work? As per my experiment, it will bake to keyframe every rigid body object you selected.

Comment: Just as @HarryMcKenzie says, select all and then choose _Bake to Keyframes_. Have you even tried it before asking the question?